# Can't debug stored procedure after upgrading to Windows 7

Tags: sql-server, windows-7

After upgrading to Windows 7, I can no longer debug stored procecures in SQL server management studio (MSSSMS). I get the message "Failed to start debugger". Data is Null. This method or property cannto be called on Null values (System.Data). I tried starting MSSMS with "Run as administrator", but the same thing happens. Any ideas?
Thanks, Brian

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to a permission error for debugging.

Try setting these settings

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1bhybwz(v=VS.80).aspx

To debug on SQL Server,  both the account running Visual Studio and the account used to connect to SQL Server must be members of the sysadmin role.

The account used to connect to SQL Server is either your Windows user account (if you are using Windows authentication) or an account with user ID and password (if you use SQL authentication).

Answer (score 0):

I was going to reinstall SQL Server, and then discovered there is now SQL Server 2008 SP2. I intalled that and it fixed it.

Comment: I am on 2012 SP3 and still cannot debug. None of the solutions found online helped. Added permissions to registry keys, no access denied errors in Procmon, but still no go. Huge shame on MS for releasing so bugged debugger and claiming it worked. BOO HOO!

Answer (score 0):

For me installation of SQLServer2012-KB4016762-x64.exe worked. I did apply Tom's answer from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bc1d8e04-723e-4340-9595-c94dced8580a/failed-to-start-debugger-data-is-null-sql-server-2012?forum=sqltools) prior to that, but it alone did not resolve the problem.